# Problem setting WhatId with a custom object ID

Tags: apex, custom-object, event, whatid

I have the following error :

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION ... [WhatID]

When I'm trying to create an `Event` setting the `WhatId` field with a custom object ID. With Account Id it works.

```
Event event = new Event();
event.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
event.Subject = 'Test';
event.StartDateTime = ...;
event.EndDateTime = ...;
event.whatId = (Id)customObjectId; // Here my customObjectID = a01b000000LWZWGAA1
```

My custom object is not a child of any standard objects.
And when I inspect the schema, the `whatId` field has several `Reference To`  like Account, Contract, Opportunity but my custom object is not listed !

Is it possible to do that ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution few times after create the post.
I let it for help other.

So I needed to check the 'Allow activities' checkbok in the custom object details page (Setup > Create > Objects).

After that, I was able to create an `Event`.