# How do I set whatid to a custom object

Tags: apex, whatid

I can’t set the what Id to the Id of a custom object.
This has been asked before, but the answers aren't helping me:
[So many failures](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DMO4QAO)
[Including this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66592/problem-setting-whatid-with-a-custom-object-id)

I took a picture of my custom object setting:

[image: Allow activities]

Here's my test code:

```
static testmethod void makeTask(){
        Engagement__c em = new Engagement__c();
        insert em;
        sObject[] uow = new List<sObject>();
        em.status__c = 'Open';
        Task t = new Task(whatid = em.id);
        uow.add((sObject)em);
        uow.add((sObject)t);
        system.debug('> '+json.serialize(uow));
        Database.UpsertResult[] objUpsertResult = Database.Upsert(uow,false);
        System.Debug('> upsert results: ' + Json.serialize(objUpsertResult));
        System.Debug('> emid: ' + em.id);
        System.Debug('> t.id: ' + t.id);
        
        Task[] t2 = [select id from Task where whatid = :em.id];
        Task fail = [select what.id  from Task where id = :t.id];
        system.debug('> fail: '+ json.serialize(fail));
        system.assert(t2.size()==1);
    }
```

This shouldn’t Fail, but it does. Here are the salient lines:

```
16:37:55.0 (82586669)|USER_DEBUG|[74]|DEBUG|> [{"attributes":{"type":"Engagement__c","url":"/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Engagement__c/a448H000000ChXUQA0"},"Id":"a448H000000ChXUQA0","Status__c":"Open"},{"attributes":{"type":"Task"},"WhatId":"a448H000000ChXUQA0"}]
16:41:04.213 (4915170299)|USER_DEBUG|[76]|DEBUG|> upsert results: [{"id":"a448H000000ChXeQAK","success":true,"errors":[],"created":false},{"id":"00T8H000007FUkjUAG","success":true,"errors":[],"created":true}]
16:41:04.213 (4915262717)|USER_DEBUG|[77]|DEBUG|> emid: a448H000000ChXeQAK
16:41:04.213 (4915310315)|USER_DEBUG|[78]|DEBUG|> t.id: 00T8H000007FUkjUAG
16:41:04.213 (4933114842)|USER_DEBUG|[82]|DEBUG|> fail: {"attributes":{"type":"Task","url":"/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Task/00T8H000007FUkjUAG"},"Id":"00T8H000007FUkjUAG"}
```

As you can see, fail.whatid is null.

The documentation had suggested that you can only use the whatid if the whoid is set to a contact.  I tested that.  It failed too.

```
static testmethod void makeTask(){
        Engagement__c em = new Engagement__c();
        insert em;
Contact c = new Contact(LastName='bryant');
insert c;
        sObject[] uow = new List<sObject>();
        em.status__c = 'Open';
        Task t = new Task(whatid = em.id, whoid = c.id);
        uow.add((sObject)em);
        uow.add((sObject)t);
        system.debug('> '+json.serialize(uow));
        Database.UpsertResult[] objUpsertResult = Database.Upsert(uow,false);
        System.Debug('> upsert results: ' + Json.serialize(objUpsertResult));
        System.Debug('> emid: ' + em.id);
        System.Debug('> t.id: ' + t.id);
        
        Task[] t2 = [select id from Task where whatid = :em.id];
        Task fail = [select what.id  from Task where id = :t.id];
        system.debug('> fail: '+ json.serialize(fail));
        system.assert(t2.size()==1);
    }
```

But then, a day later, I realized I forgot to upsert.  That's the answer, the contact was not necessary.

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate if your code is failing vs what you expect, you might want to edit your question with more details to get a better help. If you explicitly print `task.WhatId`, do you see value in it?

Comment: No, I dont. I’ll update the question

Comment: Not related (I presume), but you set the engagement status after inserting the engagement...

Comment: I note the following from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.task_fields.htm&type=5): *This field is available only when a user relates the task to a contact, not to a lead.*. The task you create doesn't have a WhoId...?

Comment: I can’t write anything civil if this is true. It fails silently, that’s the most amazing thing.

Comment: No, that wasn't it.  I've updated my code to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code.  No contact necessary.

```
static testmethod void makeTask(){
        Engagement__c em = new Engagement__c();
        insert em;
        sObject[] uow = new List<sObject>();
        em.status__c = 'Open';
        Task t = new Task(whatid = em.id);
        uow.add((sObject)em);
        uow.add((sObject)t);
        system.debug('> '+json.serialize(uow));
        Database.UpsertResult[] objUpsertResult = Database.Upsert(uow,false);
        System.Debug('> upsert results: ' + Json.serialize(objUpsertResult));
        System.Debug('> emid: ' + em.id);
        System.Debug('> t.id: ' + t.id);
        
        Task[] t2 = [select id from Task where whatid = :em.id];
        Task fail = [select what.id  from Task where id = :t.id];
        system.debug('> fail: '+ json.serialize(fail));
        system.assert(t2.size()==1);
    }
```

It's dangerous out there folks.  Code with a friend.

Comment: I don't the difference between this and your original code.  Can you clarify the specific line where the fix is?

Comment: I added upsert at the end, but now somehow all my code blocks are the same.  I don't understand,  they were different to begin with because I added them at different periods of my life.  So odd.  The upshot is my new code works, but fails silently when the whois is a lead.